# Unity login doesn't work after KDE installation

Tags: 11.04, gdm

My Unity login option in GDM crashed after I installed the `kubuntu-full` and `kubuntu-desktop` packages on my Ubuntu 11.04 install.

When I’m logging into, it runs Unity 2D (which was also installed on my PC). How can I fix that?

All other login options work correctly, only the Unity ("Ubuntu") option doesn't work.

By Login option, I meant Desktop Enviroment option, which you can choose at the bottom of the GDM.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I'm logging into,"? Can you clear that up for us?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)